# Linking stylesheet to html - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, stylesheet, href

HTML- code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="no">

</head>
    <title>Thomas</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<h4>A major headline</h4>
<p> Some text
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

For some weird reason, my css properties wont show when I try to load this page. The html file is saved thomas.html, whilst the css file is saved style.css in the same folder as thomas.html

Why won´t it work? :(

Comment: Why do you have a closing `</head>` before the `<title>`?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/18825586/thomas.html) (although you do have [machine detectable errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest-cases.dorward.me.uk%2Fstackoverflow%2F18825586%2Fthomas.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), browsers can recover from those particular ones.)

Comment: Looks like you down-voted two people who pointed out the most blatantly obvious thing, fix it instead of down-voting people trying to help you on a question where there simply isn't any subjectivity for politics. I up-voted them to negate that btw.

Comment: I haven´t downvoted anyone. At least that was not my intention. Sorry if I did :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `</head></head>`.. That should be `<head></head>`

Comment: It should be, but that is an error that browsers have no trouble recovering from.

Comment: Wow, now I feel stupid. THanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have closed the `<head>` tag twice instead of once the first one should be this
`<head>`, I just a typo error I guess you are well aware of it right